# Magento 2 : What is the Use of Varien_File_Uploader

Tags: magento2.2, image-upload

What is the use of  **Varien_File_Uploader** while uploading images in magento 2

Comment: Please have a look in to the following post, http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-upload-file/   and   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142702/upload-a-file-on-customer-registration-page-magento-2/142711

Comment: Is this possible to use this in magento2.2

Comment: Go through the second link to know more about, this in magento2.2